# What is the mental model I should have for CreationalContexts?

Tags: jboss-weld

I will present this example as simply as I know how.

I have a `Grandparent` class whose constructor accepts a `Parent`.  I have a `Parent` class whose constructor accepts a `Child`. I have a `Child` class whose constructor accepts nothing.

- The `Grandparent` is (arbitrarily) in `Dependent` scope.
- The `Parent` is (importantly) in `Singleton` scope.
- The `Child` is (importantly) in `Dependent` scope.

I have implemented custom beans for each of these so that their `destroy` methods will be invoked (otherwise Weld optimizes away the need for a destroy call).

The grandparent's `Bean` will create a `Grandparent` instance like this:

```
return new Grandparent((Parent)bm.getReference(bm.resolve(bm.getBeans(Parent.class)), Parent.class, cc));
```

Note in particular I use the supplied `CreationalContext` as the `Contextual#create(CreationalContext)` method documentation instructs.

The `Parent` bean does the same sort of thing, but asking obviously for a `Child` reference.

(These mechanics are (deliberately) exactly what Weld (*et al.*) uses to implement its injection machinery.)

In my test code:

I create a `CreationalContext` to use for the anticipated `Grandparent` construction:

```
CreationalContext<Grandparent> gpcc = bm.createCreationalContext(grandparentBean);
```

I get a `Grandparent` contextual reference using that `gpcc`:

```
Grandparent gp = (Grandparent)bm.getReference(grandparentBean, Grandparent.class, gpcc);
```

At this point, when I inspect `gpcc`, I note that it has two dependent objects in it in its `parentDependentInstances` collection and zero in its `dependentInstances` collection.  (Note that it, of course, has no parent.)

My mental model *had* been that given a `Bean`, `GPB`, creating a `Grandparent` instance, `GP`, the `CreationalContext` used at creation time, `GPCC`, will contain any dependent-scoped instances "belonging to" `GP` (which is exactly zero).  Under this (flawed?) mental model, if I were to call `release()` on `GPCC` it would effectively do nothing.

Instead I'm seeing that `GPCC` contains:

- information to destroy `GP`
- information to destroy `C`, where `C` is the `Child` instance that `GP` knows nothing about

Naïvely, it looks like `Child` has been added as a dependent object of `Grandparent` in some way. This surprised me. If I destroy `Grandparent`, surely I shouldn't destroy `Child`?

To be clear: when I use the `grandparentBean` to destroy `Grandparent`, supplying it with `gpcc`, `Child` is not in fact destroyed. So everything works, but I don't know how.

It seems my mental model is flawed. What is the proper mental model that explains this state of affairs?

(I wonder if I'm hitting side effects of https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WELD-2743. If the child `CreationalContext` is not created, then the parent dependent instances, it would seem, are never "seen".)

Update: my mental model is definitely being whipsawed by WELD-2743's changes. `getInjectableReference` *does* create child `CreationalContext`s, as it always has, but `getReference` no longer does for reasons I don't fully understand.

Comment: Filed https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WELD-2745; we'll see